# Animation series in which the protoganist got gloves which help him to control a robot

Tags: story-identification

I came across an animation series in which the protoganist got gloves which help him to control a robot. Later, with the help of that robot, he fights the aliens which invade Earth. Does anyone know about this series?

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! This really isn't much to go on; is there anything else at all you remember about this show? Please [consult this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/76048) and let us know whether there's any other details you can tell us.

Comment: @F1Krazy - There's also a guide specifically for anime questions; [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)